# For some reason the "new" method is protected on a subclass of Graphql-ruby's BaseConnection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, ruby-on-rails-5, graphql-ruby

The error I'm getting is:

```
NoMethodError Exception: protected method `new' called for Connections::MySubclassConnection:Class
```

I've implemented a `BaseConnection < GraphQL::Types::Relay::BaseConnection` in `base_connection.rb` and then created a subclass `class Connections::MySubclassConnection < Types::BaseConnection` in `my_subclass_connection.rb`.

This error is being raised in my root query in the connection field:

```
field :my_subclass_connection, ...
def my_subclass_connection
 Connections::MySubclassConnection.new( <--- error is being raised here
      Connections::MySubclassItems.new(
        ...
      ),
    )
end
```

Comment: Show your `initialize` method of `Connections::MySubclassConnection`.

Comment: I don't have an initializer defined for `Connections::MySubclassConeection`, since I assumed it's inheriting from `Schema::Object`. Referencing these docs: https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/1.12.8/GraphQL/Types/Relay/BaseConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Connections::MySubclassConeection something like

```
def initialize
  super
end
```

But before you do this, check the docs of `Types::BaseConnection` whether they expect you to do something particular in your constructor before invoking the one of the base class.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I think I figured the issue out. I was trying to initialize a "Type" subclass which should be the return type for the resolver. I didn't need to change inheritance for the Connections::MySubclassConnection which was originally inheriting from GraphQL::Pagination::Connection. It works just fine now when using the Types::BaseConnection subclass as the field return type.

Answer (score 0):

`Types::BaseConnection` should be used as the return type for the resolver. Not as a replacement for `GraphQL::Pagination::Connection`. You can make a custom BaseConnection to add extra fields to your Connection.

```
field :my_subclass_connection, ...
def my_subclass_connection
 Connections::MySubclassConnection.new( <--- This class was a "Types" subclass which should be used to define the return type for the resolver. 
      Connections::MySubclassItems.new(
        ...
      ),
    )
end
```

Comment: I still don't get how you managed to fix it... Can you add more details please?

Comment: PS nevermind, figured it out: I had to nest my custom connection class from `GraphQL::Pagination::Connection` rather than from `BaseConnection` (which in its turn is nested from `GraphQL::Types::Relay::BaseConnection`).
So current setup is:
`Connections::MySubclassConnection < GraphQL::Pagination::Connection`.
I also had to make sure there's a `def nodes` method in custom connection.